# Pressing Back Button (Hardware) from Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin, prism

am working on a XF project with Prism. I have a Login Page, which on success navigates to a Master Detail Page.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Text="Title1" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="DetailNavigationPage/Page1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
```

I have 4 buttons in the Master Page, which I am using for navigation as shown in code above.

This works fine, in the sense, i can navigate to my detail pages, and use the hamburger icon to view master page again.

However, when i click the Back Button (hardware), i am pushed back to Login page instead of Master Page. Is there anything I could do to show my Master Page when I press Back Button ?

Thanks

Comment: You could remove the Login Page from the navigation stack?

Comment: Could you pls let me know how can i do that ?

Comment: Use the static class Navigation and call RemovePage with the page you want to remove.

Comment: I tried that, in fact in the constructor of my Master Page. However, Navigation.NavigationStack seems empty at that point

Comment: You can't do it in the ctor as the page has not been navigated to yet when it gets invoked. You need to do it in one of the lifecycle events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent navigation back to the LoginPage, the best thing to do is to remove it from the Navigation Stack. If your navigation call on a successful login is:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync( "MainPage" );
```

Your navigation stack actually looks like: `LoginPage/MainPage`. While your application may not provide a way to navigate back, as you have discovered a hardware back button can still accomplish the task. If on the other hand you change your navigation call to look like:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync( "/MainPage" );
```

It will make "MainPage" the root page of your application.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That looks to be the solution I was searching for. However, when i click back now, instead of Master Page being displayed, the app gets minimized. It is as if, the Master Page never exists in the Stack, despite Login Navigating to Master as you had mentioned. Is that an expected behavior ?

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior. As I recall for both Windows and Android, pressing the hardware back button effectively minimizes your application if pressed while on the root page.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Is there any specific reason why Master Page never gets into the stack ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it not being on the stack. You may want to get more help on the [Prism Slack channel](https://prismslack.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks, what i meant was, is there a way I could invoke the Master Page when pressing back button. When i inspect the stack in one of the detail page, it looks like the Master Page is never there.